# Determining what user context a calling application is.

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms

I have a reusable data access component that is being used in Winform apps and Web apps. Part of the module needs to log the user that is making any changes to the data. i.e. CreatedBy or ModifiedBy

If the component was being used strictly for Winform access I could use WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name to get the current user's name and if the component was being used only in web apps I could use HttpContext to get the use name.

What I would like to do is make the component flexible enough that it can be used in both situations. So how do I detect what type of app is calling the component so that I can examine the resulting context for the user name?

Comment: I believe that `WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name` would return the IIS process user name, if it has that you can then use HttpContext to get the username.

Comment: Yes it returning the process username but I'm not sure how that would be useful to determine the httpContext. If I hard code a check for a specific process name then I lose the flexibility of using the module elsewhere.

Comment: Another option would be to inject an "identity provider" service into your module. The Winforms app would inject the provider for the windows identity and the ASP application would inject the provider for web identity. You could also check the `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()` to see if it is the winforms app or the IIS one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always check to see if `HttpContext` even exists. If it doesn't (`HttpContext.Current = null`), you're not running a web application.

```
var httpContext = HttpContext.Current;
var userName = (httpContext == null) 
             ? WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name 
             : httpContext.User.Identity.Name;
```

Another approach is just to use the current thread's principal, if you are setting it (you should be):

```
var principal = System.Threading.Thead.CurrentPrincipal;
var userName = principal.Identity.Name;
```

Comment: I ended up using the first suggestion. Can you elaborate on your second approach a bit? Specifically your (you should be) comment.

Comment: A typical web app will deserialize the authentication token (e.g. the forms auth cookie), read the user information, and assign a principal to the thread, all before any control passes to a page or controller. But this is all very customizable, so there's a chance you're not doing it.

Comment: Ok makes sense. 99% of web we are doing is internal only using windows authentication so dealing with the principal is mostly all taken care of for us. Thanks

Comment: I would consider anyway @Ron Beyer advice to Inject somehow an "Identity provider service" in your code: this will decouple your code from the method used to retrieve the current user. Also, it will make possibile a future implementation that does not rely on windows identity (e.g. a web application used by external users)